# ValueError when trying to save to ImageField

Tags: django, django-models, imagefield

## AIM

In **views.py**, I create an `Alarm` object from the `search_text` entered on a `Form` and the associated `locations` got from the Twitter API.

Now, I'd like to render some visualization of the data in **results.html**. Specifically, I'd like to create a histogram based on `Location.country` data.

The following code successfully saves a save a file ("histogram.png") with the correct data:

```
@property
def get_histogram(self):
    """ Function to create a histogram of locations associated with search_text """
    location_freq = self.display_locations()
    plt.bar(list(location_freq.keys()), location_freq.values(), color='g')
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig('histogram.png')
```

However, I'd like to save the file to `Alarm.histogram` so that I can render the file in **results.html**.

Although, perhaps it is far more appropriate to save the histogram in **views.py** instead of in an instance method in **models.py**.

## ERROR

```
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: The 'histogram' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

## CODE

**Models.py**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    """ Model representing a Location (attached to Hashtag objects through a M2M relationship) """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=14000)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tweet_date = models.DateTimeField()

class Hashtag(models.Model):
    """ Model representing a specific Hashtag serch by user """
    search_text = models.CharField(max_length=140, primary_key=True)
    location = models.ManyToManyField(Location, blank=True)
    histogram = models.ImageField(upload_to='img', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.search_text

    def display_locations(self):
        """ Function to create a dict by frequency of the locations associated with search_text """
        country_list = list(self.location.values_list('country', flat=True).all())
        for country in country_list:
            location_freq = {i:country_list.count(i) for i in set(country_list)}
            return location_freq

    @property
    def get_histogram(self):
        """ Function to create a histogram of locations associated with search_text """
        location_freq = self.display_locations()
        plt.bar(list(location_freq.keys()), location_freq.values(), color='g')
        file_location = 'mapping_twitter/static/mapping_twitter/images/histogram.png'
        plt.show()
        plt.savefig(file_location)
        f = open(file_location)
        self.histogram.save('histogram.png', File(f))
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="{{ hashtag.histogram.url }}" alt="Histogram" />
```

Comment: Probably that object has no image in the database. Try checking with image exist with if condition in the template

Comment: @AniketPawar, I checked and the image doesn't exist. I am attempting to create the image and save it to the database in `get_histogram`. Do you know how to do so?

Comment: what does that mean you want to store image in get_histogram ? You can add image in the db field histogram itself.

Comment: @AniketPawar, I have updated the question to include more information. I'm attempting to use the method: `get_histogram` to 'draw' the histogram (based on data in the db) and then save that histogram to the `Alarm.histogram` field. I suspected, although I may be wrong, I couldn't add image in the db field because the image depends on data in the db and therefore changes each time the User loads the page. Apologies if my limited understanding isn't clear.